# Catching events for mousewheel when Firefox is autoscrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mouseevent, jquery-events

I know there are many questions asking how to prevent the autoscrolling mode that Firefox activates when a page is bigger than the viewport and you press the middle mouse button.

But what I actually need is just being able to detect the `mouseup` event, when autoscrolling is active. The event just doesn't seem to propagate, so I don't know when (and more important where) the mouse button is released.

I could also settle for detecting when the autoscrolling mode is gone and the mouse usage is back to normal.

I've prepared a [Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/PzAt9e/preview) to play with. When it starts, middle click anywhere and the text in the box will update. If you press the button, more content is added to the page: middle click will activate autoscrolling and the `mouseup` event is lost forever.

[Link](http://embed.plnkr.co/PzAt9e/preview)

Answer (score 1):

Does this give a result?

```
$(selector).live('mouseup', function(e) { 

    if(e.which == 1) {

        alert("left");

    }if(e.which == 3) {

        alert("right button");

    }else if(e.which == 2) {

        alert("middle button"); 

    }

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: `.live` was deprecated and removed.

Comment: Same here. The third `alert` is never executed when autoscrolling.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("your id").on('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     alert("left button");
   } else if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     alert("right button");
   } else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
   e.preventDefault();
}).on('contextmenu', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p49nF/

Hope,this helps.!!!

Comment: Use `.on` instead of `.bind` -- it is the more _standard_ way now.

Comment: Click doesn't seem to propagate as well.

Comment: @DekDekku:click and scroll are two different think.There is a different event for scrolling-->onmousewhell

Comment: @DekDekku:what do you want scrolling or click?

Comment: I'm not interested in scrolling. I'm interested in mouseup, as specified in my question.

Comment: I mean, `click` would be OK too, but I've already ruled out that it could possibly work.

Comment: Yes, I have. Have you?

Comment: 1) You're detecting mousedown. 2) Your page is not bigger that the viewport, therefore autoscrolling is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Even tho' Pieter's answer is not correct, it gave me the correct idea.

For some reason if you `preventDefault()` in the `mousedown` handler, the `mouseup` one starts working.

```
$(document)
  .on("mousedown", function(e) {
      if (e.which !== 2) return;
      $("#h").text("MouseDown");
      e.preventDefault();
    }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
      if (e.which !== 2) return;
      $("#h").text("MouseUp");
    });
```

[Plunk with the solution](http://embed.plnkr.co/MuYtJe/preview)

Comment: Glad,you got your answer.
+1 to pietrs if that helped.

Comment: Me too: got a bigger one now, but it can wait:D I see that your fiddle also used .preventDefault() It just didn't reproduce the problem I had.

Comment: Solutions matter..not their resources.Good luck with your project

Comment: Everything matters in its own way. (Thanks.)